# Ruby - Hash.Select with variable

Tags: ruby

trying to pass a variable rule in select enumerator

```
match = companies.select{ |x| x[rule] > 10  }

data.each do |item|
   item.each do |file_name,filter_settings|
     if file_name == "out1_1x.csv"
       output_file = file_name
       current_filter = filter_settings
       rule = filter_settings[:rule].to_sym
       condition = filter_settings[:condition]
       amount = filter_settings[:amount]
       p rule   # here i have :price
          match = companies.select{ |x| x[rule] > 10  }
         puts match
      end
    end
end
```

but getting an error:

> undefined method '>'

for nil class even if in the rule is assigned value.

```
companies.select{ |x| x[:price] > 10  }
```

This assigment is ok.

Companies are defined as array of hashes with structure :

```
{:name=>"ABC company", :code=>"RDCX", :price=>33,:volume=>79560}
{:name=>"DEF", :code=>"FFF", :price=>41, :volume=>367491}
```

I also would like to ask, its there any option how to pass in to the select enumerator the "full parameter set" from "external variables - rule, condition,amount" ?

Something like

```
match = companies.select{ |x| x[rule] condition amount  }
Where condition is - ">", "<" "=" ?
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the he [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-send) method:

```
companies =[{:name=>"ABC company", :code=>"RDCX", :price=>33,:volume=>79560},
   {:name=>"DEF", :code=>"FFF", :price=>41, :volume=>367491}]
rule = :price
condition = :>
amount = 35

p companies.select{|h| h[rule].send(condition, amount)}

# => [{:name=>"DEF", :code=>"FFF", :price=>41, :volume=>367491}]
```

Comment: Be careful though, since send can call all methods. If you want to exclude private methods you might want to use *#public_send* (see link) instead. Or if you only allow certain operators you might want to create a whitelist of operations to call. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send